# Python & Azure cli backup comand : is misspelled or not recognized by the system

Tags: python, json, azure, command-line-interface

I´m developing the following script to check differents backups and keep alive the process until the backup has been finished.

**SCRIPT:**

```
from azure.cli.core import get_default_cli
import subprocess
import json


#VARS
AZCLIusr="CREDENTIALS"
AZCLIpwd="CREDENTIALS"
AZCLItenant="CREDENTIALS"
#######
print("#### LOGIN AZ #####")
get_default_cli().invoke(['login', '--service-principal', '--username', str(AZCLIusr), '-p', str(AZCLIpwd), '--tenant', str(AZCLItenant)])

print ("### VM LIST COMMAND #####")

##VARS##
rgAZ="RESOURCEGROUPNAME"
startDate="30-08-2021"
query="[?contains (properties.containerName, \'VMNAME\')].properties.status"
####

process = subprocess.Popen(['az','backup', 'job', '--resource-group', rgAZ, '--start-date', startDate, '--vault-name myRecoveryServicesVault' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
jsonLoads = json.loads(out)    

print("### PRINT JSON FORMAT #####")
print(json.dumps(jsonLoads, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
print("### PRINT STRING FORMAT #####")
print(jsonLoads)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ERROR: 'VMNAME' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

TRY THIS:

https://aka.ms/cli_ref
Read more about the command in reference docs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "5py.py", line 24, in <module>
    jsonLoads = json.loads(out)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Looks like don´t like the quotes ('') in the query sentence. It works with anther simply commands:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['az','vm','list', '-o', 'json'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
jsonLoads = json.loads(out)
```

If I launch AZ QUERY through the terminal it works correctly:

**AZ CLI QUERY:**

```
az backup job list --resource-group RESOURCEGROUP--start-date 30-08-2021 --vault-name myRecoveryServicesVault --query "[?contains (properties.containerName, 'VMNAME')].properties.status"
Command group 'backup' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
[
  "Completed"
]
```

How can I avoid this misspelled? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cloud profile used to 'latest' was found useful in some similar instances.

Try as below:

```
az cloud set --name AzureCloud --profile "latest"
```

See: [Manage registered Azure clouds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cloud?view=azure-cli-latest#:%7E:text=09-01-hybrid%2C-,latest,-Global%20Parameters)